# AJAX/PHP Form Sending on Local Server and not live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

So I'm having a weird issue where a contact form I created works on my localhost but will not work live. I'm using AJAX and PHP for the form. When I send it both live and local, I get no errors in my code. On the live server, the form allows me to submit and gives a success message but the message never gets sent. Not quite sure why it works locally but fails on the live server.

Here's the code for the form:

```
<form class="column small-12 medium-6 large-6 contact-form" id="formContact" action="contact-form-post2.php" method="post">

<div class="row">

    <div class="column large-12">

        <div class="contactResponse"></div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="column large-12">

        <input type="text" name="firstLastName"  id="cname" placeholder="First & Last Name" value required>
    </div>

</div>
<!--/.row -->

<div class="row">

    <div class="column large-12">

        <input type="email" name="email" id="cemail"  placeholder="Email" value required>
    </div>

</div>
<!--/.row -->

<div class="row">

    <div class="column large-12">

        <textarea name="message" rows="10" id="ccomment" value required></textarea>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">

    <div class="column large-12">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="button submit">Submit</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the code for the form validation and and submission

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name    = $_POST['firstLastName'];
    $email   = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to      = "shekinahc.smith@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Website Contact Form Message";
    $headers = "From: $email";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
 ?>


 $("#formContact").validate({

    // converting error message to placeholder to style with red background
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        element.attr("placeholder", error[0].outerText);
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'contact-form-post2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {

                var submit = $(form).find( 'button[type="submit"]' );

                $( ".contactResponse" ).html('Your message has been sent. We will contact you soon.');

                submit.text('Sent, Thank you');

                submit.attr("disabled", true); 
            }            
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where you have called $("#formContact").validate();

Comment: @AjeetKumar In side my main js file within document ready

Comment: @ShekinahSmith please check my answer and upvote/mark as accepted answer if this fixes your issue. Thanks :)

Comment: @SubinThomas that won't change or solve anything

Answer (score 1):

There were a few issues in your code, try this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['firstLastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $to = "shekinahc.smith@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Website Contact Form Message";
    $headers = "From: test@{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#formContact").validate({
        // converting error message to placeholder to style with red background
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            element.attr("placeholder", error[0].outerText);
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'contact-form-post2.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    var submit = $(form).find('button[type="submit"]');
                    $(".contactResponse").html('Your message has been sent. We will contact you soon.');
                    submit.text('Sent, Thank you');
                    submit.attr("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<form class="column small-12 medium-6 large-6 contact-form" id="formContact" action="contact-form-post2.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column large-12">
            <div class="contactResponse"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column large-12">
            <input type="text" name="firstLastName" id="firstLastName" placeholder="First & Last Name" value required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column large-12">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column large-12">
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" id="ccomment" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column large-12">
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="button submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The key change is that the `From` address in the mail headers were using the users `POST`'ed email, which will have a different domain to the test/live server. This often prevents the mail from reaching it's destination however somehow must be allowed from your live server.

Another thing noticed: 2 form fields had 2 different id's declared, rendering the html invalid and this can cause js errors in some cases - each html element can have only 1 single id attribute.

Comment: @ShekinahSmith is all of this code just contained in 1 script that is posting back to itself?

Comment: So, I initially tried it by splitting my code up how I originally had it where the php was in the post2 file, the JS was in my project.js file and the form within the html. That produced the same result I was having where it "submit" the form and give the success message. The way, took the js out of the project.js file and put it in script tags below the form and kept the php separate in the post2 file, that time, on submit it loaded the post2 page in the browser which was a blank white page

Answer (score 1):

So I started going through my hosting and I had an htaccess file from a previous project left on my test subdomain. Once I deleted it, everything started working.

Comment: Excellent. Would you mind upvoting my answer for the code improvement suggestions and bugfixes? Many thanks, glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: @ajmedway done! Thanks for helping at 4am though! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem! Can't see the upvote on my answer though?

Comment: @ajmedway it won't show my upvote until I'm at a level 15 reputation :(